# How to center a scaled down div within a flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a split screen, with a `fixed` right side. Left hand side will be a markdown editor, but with different configurations and styles to add to the output text.

Whereas the right hand side will basically be a preview. Left hand side is scrollable, and right hand side isn't.

After completing the form, users will be able to print out whatever they create basically. So to `preview` this, I created a `content` div (that will be printed out) with 210mm x 297mm dimensions to mimic A4 format.

What I want to do is to shrink it down using `scale`, to show the entire preview of the page to the user, but I want to have it vertically centered.

Here is the sandbox for it:
https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-cloud-cgsnd0?file=/index.html

And to see the actual issue, just uncomment width, height and scale, within `content` class.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Paulie_D.
Always give direct code snippets, in this case scale doesn't matter for you, flexbox is a responsive tool, and question is actually just how do you center that div in your setup.

To give others context this is the setup:

```html
<div class="main-col second">
  <header>...</header>
  <main>
    <div class="content">...</div>
  </main>
  <footer>...</footer>
</div>
```

```css
.main-col.second {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.main-col.second main {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

You have two options:

- Apply flex-box to the main element inside the .second div.

```css
.main-col.second main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

- Or remove the entire styling for the selector `.main-col.second main` and add `justify-content: space-between` to your `.main-col.second` selector.

Comment: Hey @magnusjensen, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately non of those options work in my case. If I add those, then the footer is not visible at all..